# Show and hide elements of ng-repeat cycle

Tags: angularjs

Here is my HTML:

```
    <ul class="no-bullet">
        <li ng-repeat="(group, count) in info.info">

            <a href="#" ng-click="getQuestions(group)"
               ng-mouseenter="showGroupPanel()" ng-mouseleave="hideGroupPanel()"
                    >{{group}} ({{count}}) </a>

            <div class="group_panel" ng-show="hoveringGroup">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
            </div>

        </li>
```

And here is my JS:

```
    $scope.hoveringGroup = false;

    $scope.showGroupPanel = function() {
        $scope.hoveringGroup = true;
    }

    $scope.hideGroupPanel = function() {
        $scope.hoveringGroup = false;
    }
```

When user mouseover one of elements of the list additional div (group_panel) is displayed.  But it is displayed for all elements of the list.  How can I fix it to display "group-panel" div only for one element (mouseovered) of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way : use ng-repeat's isolate scope. (hoveringGroup will be a separate variable for each ng-repeat iteration)

```
<ul class="no-bullet">
    <li ng-repeat="(group, count) in info.info">

        <a href="#" ng-click="getQuestions(group)"
           ng-mouseenter="hoveringGroup = true" ng-mouseleave="hoveringGroup = false"
                >{{group}} ({{count}}) </a>

        <div class="group_panel" ng-show="hoveringGroup">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>

    </li>
```

You could also store the information in your repeated item :

```
<ul class="no-bullet">
    <li ng-repeat="info in info.info">

        <a href="#" ng-click="getQuestions(info.group)"
           ng-mouseenter="showGroupPanel(info)" ng-mouseleave="hideGroupPanel(info)"
                >{{info.group}} ({{info.count}}) </a>

        <div class="group_panel" ng-show="info.hoveringGroup">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>

    </li>

$scope.showGroupPanel = function(info) {
    info.hoveringGroup = true;
}

$scope.hideGroupPanel = function(info) {
    info.hoveringGroup = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.info = {


    info: [{
        id: 1
      }, {
        id: 2
      }, {
        id: 3
      }

    ]

  }

  $scope.hoveringGroup = false;

  $scope.showGroupPanel = function(level) {
    level.hoveringGroup = true;

  }

  $scope.hideGroupPanel = function(level) {
    level.hoveringGroup = false;
  }

  $scope.createlevel = function(count, level) {

    return angular.copy(count, level)

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <ul class="no-bullet">
      <li ng-repeat="(group, count) in info.info" ng-init="level =createlevel(count,level)">

        <a href="#" ng-click="getQuestions(group)" ng-mouseenter="showGroupPanel(level)" ng-mouseleave="hideGroupPanel(level)">{{group}} ({{count}}) </a>

        <div class="group_panel" ng-show="level.hoveringGroup">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>


  </div>
</div>
```